# enabling/disabling a gwt spanelement

Tags: gwt, widget

how can i programatically enable/disable a com.google.gwt.dom.client.SpanElement

i need to have methods like setEnabled(boolean enabled) and isEnabled();

SpanElement does not expose those .

Also if some one can explain me the use of spanelement it would be great

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="container">
    <div class="{style.column}">
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="pendingBillingCheckBox"></g:CheckBox><br clear="all" />
        <span class="{baseCSS.getApplicationCSS.label}">Tech $:</span>
        <span class="{baseCSS.getApplicationCSS.label}" ui:field="techCost"></span><br clear="all" />
        <span class="{baseCSS.getApplicationCSS.label}">Prof $:</span>
        <span class="{baseCSS.getApplicationCSS.label}" ui:field="prof"></span><br clear="all" />
        <g:TextBox addStyleNames="{style.profText}"></g:TextBox>
    </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

i would like to enable/disable the techCost and prof UI fields

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe tell us what you want to do? Span is normally used to style text using css, why would you want to enable them? Just for styling puposes?

Comment: i have edited my question.i would like to enable/disable the techCost and prof ui fields

Comment: What effect should the enabling/disabling have? Again, span are used to display text and style it the way you want. Enabling/disabling widgets is used to stop interactions with widgets, e.g. a button to save someting is disabled at the beginning and therefore cannot recieve any actions like clicks. Once something is edited the save button would be enabled so you can click on it to save.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
spanElement.getStyle().setDisplay(Style.Display.NONE);
```